# I blocked internet access for my Xbox Series S and now games don't even start. How-To play offline?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, microsoft-flight-simulator

On [r/xbox](https://teddit.net/r/xbox/comments/smo1qz/can_play_my_on_xbox_series_s_offline/) people say you can play games on Xbox Series S without internet (even Game Pass stuff).

I have had a different experience. I have blocked internet for Xbox in OpenWrt router and now the flight simulator does not start at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Why do people on Reddit say you can play games offline, but for me the startup aborts with an error message.

Comment: In my memory, MSFS HEAVILY relies on Internet - since it always downloads maps from their server since it's too large to store them locally (I've heard it's petabyte in size). But this information is based on when the MSFS was launched, it might have changed since then. I doubt it has though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of games, including Microsoft Flight Simulator, HEAVILY relies on Internet - since it always downloads maps from their server since it's too large to store them locally. As I searched into it, the map is actually 2 Petabytes according to [PCGamer](https://www.pcgamer.com/microsoft-wants-to-bring-back-flight-simulator-to-show-it-supports-pc/):

> Spencer says that 2 petabytes of geographical data is used to seamlessly stitch together Earth.

Therefore, you will need to be online to play Microsoft Flight Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

As per Xbox Support page [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/connect-network/using-xbox-one-offline)

When your Xbox is offline, you can:

- Watch TV
- Sign in to your profile (if you've signed in online before)
- Change console settings (except for profile and family settings; content controls remain in place while offline)
- Play games (provided you've set this as your home Xbox or have a game disc)
- Save game clips and screenshots
- Earn achievements (however, there's limited offline space for game captures and achievements, so you should go online every so often to sync them)

**So I'm guessing you will have to set the Xbox as home Xbox.**

> To change your Home Xbox, go to Settings. Then under the General
> settings, select
> Personalization > My home Xbox.
>
> Once you're in the My home Xbox menu you can choose to make the Xbox
> you're on your new home Xbox.

Comment: Some games also require connectivity. This is not something that can be blocked on the level of the console. MSFS pulls a lot of map data in and I'm unsure of it has an offline mode.